# How retrieve all nodes linked by a relationship

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j, I have nodes with two properties: name and id. I have an index on id.
I have relationships "CALL" with a property: "by_test". This property can take different value (id of any node).

**Two nodes can have multiple CALL relationships** with different by_test property value.

So let's say I have 1..N nodes linked by the same CALL.by_test property value.

Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 -> .. -> Node N

- How can I get all these nodes?

  1. Do I need to put an Index on the relationship?
  2. Do I have to create dynamic relationship? Instead of CALL.by_test=value, use value has a relationship.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cypher, you could query for that list like this:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name="one") 
MATCH p=(n)-[r:CALL*1..]->(m)
WHERE ALL(x in r WHERE x.by_test = 3)
RETURN n,m
```

In the `MATCH` you bind a term `r` to the `CALL` relationships, which you then use in the `WHERE` clause to check the `by_test` property of each.

As Michael Hunger noted, the `r` is a collection of relationships, so the `WHERE` needs to use `ALL` to check each of the relationships.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? The syntax is shifting a bit.

Comment: as `r` in this case (variable length path) stands for 1..n relationships you have to use: `WHERE ALL(x in r : x.by_test=3)`